# Regarding the connection between an FTP Server and a Database Server

Tags: mysql, database, server, ftp, filezilla

Good day, to make a long story short I was given access to an FTP server in order to upload files to an online website using FileZilla and was given the following:

- FTP Username
- FTP Password
- FTP Server
- Port Number

When I tried to asked our "consultant" about access to details to connect to a database server, I was told that I should know how to get in since I was given FTP server access.

However when I downloaded MySQL Workbench to try and edit the database, the the details (or parameters) are different to what I was given to access the FTP.

I would just like to know if I could access the database using FTP credentials or if both need completely separate details to connect. Thanks for any help/advice.

FTP (FileZilla):
[image: FTP]

SQL (MySQL Workbench):
[image: SQL]

EDIT:

I use xampp in order to edit an offline version of the database to test before I upload new code into filezilla. I added new columns with ease offline but It does not show online.

For more information:

- I have another person editing database info on the online website
- The offline version information is completely different and does not update.
- I have added a new column in the offline database but there is no update on the website's online version.
- This means that there is an online database that I cannot access since I do not have credentials.

Comment: You didn't really explain why are you even trying to access database, and why do you thing there's any database at all.

Comment: i was given access to a website that is already online with a database, i can edit it no problem using filezilla but i cannot do anything about the online database.

Comment: Then you need to ask for information about access to database. FTP credentials won't help you with that. Unless those credentials are more then just FTP credentials.

Comment: thank you I am just making sure both information are different. now im baffled why our "consultant" told me that my question about getting database access is redundant since he gave me FTP login info.

Comment: Maybe you are not supposed to have database access. It may not be available remotely. Maybe only the server-side scripts can access the database (locally - on the server).

Comment: another final note: i use xampp in order to edit an offline version of the database to test before i upload new code into filezilla. I added new columns with ease offline but It does not show online. (updated my question)

Comment: This is a completely new question, so please post it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP and database accesses are two completely different and unrelated things.

While it is possible that hostname, username and password might be the same for both (while still technically separate), port number must be different.

Maybe you are not supposed to have a database access. It may not be available remotely. Maybe only the server-side scripts can access the database (locally – on the server).